# Transferring a single folder from a Time Machine to a different Mac

Tags: mac, time-machine

Recently, I purchased a new MacBook and I wanted to transfer files from the old one to the new one. I used Time Machine to back up all my files from the old Mac. Is it possible to retrieve not the entire disk, but a single file or a single folder from that back-up Time Machine to a new Mac?

Comment: I would copy the contents over to an external HDD instead of using Time Machine for that.

Answer (score 4):

You can also copy the folder from Finder from `/Volumes/<Time Machine volume name>/Backups.backupdb/<Mac name>/`.

If your backup is on a network volume like a Time Capsule, open the sparse bundle file like `/Volumes/Data/Your Mac.sparsebundle/` first.

You can also run a command like `cp -a /Volumes/Time\ Machine/Backups.backupdb/Your\ Mac/2014-07-17-184058/HD/Users/username/folder ~/Desktop` or `tmutil restore /Volumes/Time\ Machine/Backups.backupdb/Your\ Mac/2014-07-17-184058/HD/Users/username/folder ~/Desktop` in a shell.

Finder and `tmutil restore` remove extended attributes like `com.apple.metadata:_kTimeMachineNewestSnapshot` but `cp` doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

> Connect the external drive that you use for Time Machine backups.Once
>   you enter Time Machine, you should see your saved backups in
>   chronological order. Scroll through your backups and look for specific
>   items or folders. Older dates are pink, newest copies are in white.
>
> Use the Search field in the Time Machine Finder window to locate the
>   file or folder you wish to restore.
>
> Use Quick Look to select what you need, and then press the spacebar to
>   view the file without having to launch its parent application.
>
> Select the file or folder, and press the Restore button. The file will
>   automatically be copied to your desktop or to the file’s original
>   folder.